# How To Check HTTP status of a list with url's using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, http-status-codes

This is My Code

```py
import requests
import sys
import time


while True:
    try:
        lists = open("master1.lst")
        for line in lists:
            time.sleep(2)
            r = requests.get(line)
            print(r.status_code(line))
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        sys.exit(str(e))
```

This Is the error i get

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='apple.com%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the lines that you get from the file, currently you have the "new line" char `\n` in the URL you are calling

```
    for line in lists:
        line = line.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much I Fixed it, but i have a small issue now how can i print the urls with the status code beside

Answer (score 0):

Also, line `print(r.status_code(line))` I believe is incorrect, because it's not a method, it's a property. You would use it like so: `print(r.status_code)`